# Deleting Data Asset in Azure ML Studio

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have created a data asset in ML Studio with a name "image_test". Since I do not use this data, I wanted to delete it and I choose to click archive. After it is archived, when I try to create new data asset with the same name it gives me error such as
*****"Data asset name already in use, choose a different name"*****
How can I handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I created one ML workspace and tried importing Dataset inside it with name **loan_test** like below:-

[image]

Data got populated like below:-

[image]

The Data set with name **loan_test** got **created** like below:-

[image]

***Now, I deleted the data set and tried creating a new data set with the same name like below:-***

[image]

Created a new Data set like below:-

[image]

The **data set got created again with the same name successfully** on my end :-

[image]

I was uploading the data set from my local file to Azure blob and then importing it. ***Also after clicking on Archive I clicked on refresh and then No data set were present, Then I created a new data set like above and it was successful.***

> Note- I performed all this tasks in the Private window of my browser to avoid cache related issues. Also, It looks like your dataset is not yet completely deleted from the back end, so try again after some time by logging into your Azure Portal in Private window > Azure ML studio > Check if no image_test data set exists > create a new data set with the same name.

**Reference:-**

[Create Data Assets - Azure Machine Learning | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-data-assets?tabs=Studio)

Comment: I tried again with your answer, but still same issue appeared. I changed my browser also to double check it.

Comment: Is the dataset still visible in the Azure ML studio? or is it deleted completely?

Comment: It is not visible in the ML Studio. Plus, I deleted the related data from blob storage but still can't create a new data with the same variable name.

Comment: Okay, Then it looks like your image_test dataset is not yet completely deleted from the back end, You need to raise a Support request on Azure Portal, Refer here -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request

Comment: Ooh I see. I wasn't aware of there is a ticket help system thanks a lot.